# Display all usernames in the "users" table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm trying to show all usernames in the users table onto my index page.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users");
$result->execute();

while ($row = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  
{
    $user = $row['users'];
    $username = $row['username'];
}

echo $user;
echo $username;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: what's the current result?

Comment: $row['users'] is not a qualified row value

Comment: iv removed the $row['users'] part, im still learning sql & php and this is the 1 thing i always get stuck on

Answer (score 0):

I think you are printing username outside of the while loop, so that you're getting the last username every time.

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users");
$result->execute();
while ($row = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo $username = $row['username'];
}
```

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/wHjqql_5RhaU94_izVpnOw.png 

that there is what im trying to achieve